# Using "row.Selected = true" changes appearence but not CurrentRow index

Tags: c#

I have the following snippet of code that searches the grid for the desired record and highlights it:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in grdActiveJobs.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells["Part Number"].Value.ToString() == lvPartNum && row.Cells["Serial Number"].Value.ToString() == lvSerialNum)
        row.Selected = true;
}
```

The above code works as intended - the row is highlighted, however, if I run a check on the currentrow.index

```
 if (grdActiveJobs.CurrentRow.Index == 0)
 {
     // Do things
 }
```

It will show the current index as 0 even if the highlighted row found by the previous snippet has an index of 5.

My question is, when the "row.selected = true" gets set, how can I also make sure that the current row index for the grid is set correctly and isn't detected as 0?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in getting the grdActiveJobs.SelectedIndex instead?

Comment: @HOKBONG Fetching this would be ideal, however I don't have the option for selected index.

Comment: You can use grid.SelectedRows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging I found this explanation:

**GridName.CurrentRow.Index** - This returns the index of the current cell as defined by the system, which will not always be the same as the user selected cell. An example of this would be if you had a grid which allowed you to select multiple rows, if you selected 10 and then deselected one of the rows, your currentrow.index would be the index of the last row you clicked on - the now unselected one.

To return the index of the currently selected row (appears highlighted to the user), you need to use **GridName.SelectedRows[0].Index**, if you only have one row selected this will return the index of the selected row. (incrementing the [0] in the previous snippet will obviously return the index the second selected row if multi-select is enabled).

My code now reads:

```
if (grdActiveJobs.SelectedRows[0].Index == 0)
{
    // Do stuff correctly
}
```

If you can improve my explanation comment and let me know :)

Comment: If you are setting the selected row programatically, why don't you check the row index at that point and then // Do stuff correctly?